# Window edge remains when moved, and cursor becomes hollow square (only showing edge line) sometimes ( vnc, Xfce4.16, Ubuntu22.04 )

Tags: 22.04, xfce, vnc

I don't know exactly when this is happenning, my cursor turns holow box(showing only edge box). I saw this when I was working remote from home but it's the same in my workplace. When I run settings manager (XApplicatios - Settings - Settings Manager), and just close, the cursor shape is restored (solid box). But I think the basic problem is that the window remains when I move the window. Please see what happens. [image]